# jquery autocomplete text input US States each state goes to different page case insensitive

Tags: jquery, redirect, bootstrap-4, autocomplete

I have a Bootstrap 4.5 website that will have:

1. Text Input with a button that needs autocomplete of all US states
2. The state entered will go to a specific page
3. The form should only accept the names of the states, no numbers etc.
4. (sounds petty but...), Search function should use the enter key and mouse key for WCAG 2.0 support.

I know we could use a dropdown redirect, but the powers that be don't like them dropdowns.

I've found pieces for autocomplete and text input, but combining them breaks my front end brain.

Below is what I've put together, still need to enable the use of the enter key + clicking on the GO button, have the "Enter a valid US State" disappear after entering vermont, and definitely cleanup on the javascript, I don't have full understanding on how to clean JS up without breaking everything.

```
<div class="text-center">
<label class="h3">Enter your state to find a plan:</label>
</div>
<p id="Vermont" class="mb-0 text-center text-primary d-none">No plans available in Vermont.</p>
<p id="empty-field" class="mb-0 text-center text-primary d-none">Please enter a US State.</p>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-inline justify-content-center">
<input type="text" id="USStates" class="typeahead form-control" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Enter Your State">
<button type="submit" id="US-Form-Submit" class="btn btn-primary">GO</button>
</div>
</div>


var urlMapping = {"ALABAMA":"./members/nationwide/","ALASKA":"./members/nationwide/","ARIZONA":"./members/nationwide/","ARKANSAS":"./members/nationwide/","CALIFORNIA":"./members/nationwide/","COLORADO":"./members/nationwide/","CONNECTICUT":"./members/nationwide/","DELAWARE":"./members/nationwide/","FLORIDA":"./members/nationwide/","GEORGIA":"./members/nationwide/","HAWAII":"./members/nationwide/","IDAHO":"./members/nationwide/","ILLINOIS":"./members/nationwide/","INDIANA":"./members/nationwide/","IOWA":"./members/nationwide/","KANSAS":"./members/nationwide/","KENTUCKY":"./members/nationwide/","LOUISIANA":"./members/nationwide/","MAINE":"./members/nationwide/","MARYLAND":"./members/nationwide/","MASSACHUSETTS":"./members/nationwide/","MICHIGAN":"./members/nationwide/","MINNESOTA":"./members/nationwide/","MISSISSIPPI":"./members/nationwide/","MISSOURI":"./members/nationwide/","MONTANA":"./members/nationwide/","NEBRASKA":"./members/nationwide/","NEVADA":"./members/nationwide/","NEW HAMPSHIRE":"./members/nationwide/","NEW JERSEY":"./members/nationwide/","NEW MEXICO":"./members/nationwide/","NEW YORK":"./members/nationwide/","NORTH CAROLINA":"./members/nationwide/","NORTH DAKOTA":"./members/nationwide/","OHIO":"./members/nationwide/","OKLAHOMA":"./members/nationwide/","OREGON":"./members/nationwide/","PENNSYLVANIA":"./members/nationwide/","RHODE ISLAND":"./members/nationwide/","SOUTH CAROLINA":"./members/nationwide/","SOUTH DAKOTA":"./members/nationwide/","TENNESSEE":"./members/nationwide/","TEXAS":"./members/nationwide/","UTAH":"./members/nationwide/","VIRGINIA":"./members/nationwide/","WASHINGTON":"./members/washington/","WEST VIRGINIA":"./members/nationwide/","WISCONSIN":"./members/nationwide/","WYOMING":"./members/nationwide/"}
$("#US-Form-Submit").click(function(){
    var input = $("#USStates").val().trim().toUpperCase();
    if (urlMapping.hasOwnProperty(input)){
        window.location = urlMapping[input],
        $("#empty-field").addClass("d-none");
    }
    else {
        $("#empty-field").removeClass("d-none");
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#USStates").keyup(function() {
        if (this.value == "Vermont") {
            $("#Vermont").removeClass("d-none"),
            $("#empty-field").addClass("d-none");
        }
        else {
            $("#Vermont").addClass("d-none"),
            $("#empty-field").addClass("d-none");
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    var states = ['Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas','California','Colorado','Connecticut','Delaware','Florida','Georgia','Hawaii','Idaho','Illinois','Indiana','Iowa','Kansas','Kentucky','Louisiana','Maine','Maryland','Massachusetts','Michigan','Minnesota','Mississippi','Missouri','Montana','Nebraska','Nevada','New Hampshire','New Jersey','New Mexico','New York','North Carolina','North Dakota','Ohio','Oklahoma','Oregon','Pennsylvania','Rhode Island','South Carolina','South Dakota','Tennessee','Texas','Utah','Vermont','Virginia','Washington','West Virginia','Wisconsin','Wyoming'];
    var states = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: states
    });
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'states',
        source: states
    });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: What's not working and what are you trying to accomplish? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello, basically it's a form with a button. The user enters the US State (or selects it from the autocomplete tooltip that pops up) and hits go or the enter button on the keyboard which then, based on the State the user enters, takes them to a specific page.

Comment: Just updated the main post, hope this helps.